# SQLite - turn-off case sensitivity on whole database

Tags: sqlite

can i turn off case sensitivity for whole database, means all the columns of all the tables ?

what happen if i have already created the database?

do i have to do it manually for all the columns setting `COLLATE` to `NOCASE`?

i have tried `NOCASE` in several queries, like following

```
select * from ...table  COLLATE NOCASE
```

but what if me or some other new person forgot to use `NOCASE`
I am tired of making every column NOCASE while creating tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `COLLATE NOCASE` on the table. If the table already exist, use `ALTER TABLE`. See here [sqlite.org](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) for Description and Examples.

**UPDATE** MrGumble is right, SQLite does not support changing collation directly with `ALTER TABLE`. You would need to go through an intermediate table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table01 (id, name countrycode, comment );
INSERT INTO table01 SELECT id, name, countrycode, comment FROM table;
DROP TABLE table;
CREATE TABLE table (
   id       integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   name     text COLLATE NOCASE
   country  integer,
   comment  text COLLATE NOCASE
);
INSERT INTO table (id, name, countrycode, comment)
    SELECT id, name, countrycode, comment FROM table01;
DROP TABLE table01;
```

There is an Application called [SQLite Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/purchase/) (with a 30 days free trial) that does this process for you.

Comment: You cannot change the `collate` on an existing column. `ALTER TABLE` can only *add* columns, or rename the entire table. Your solution would work by renaming the table, to create a *new* table, before copying in the data.

Comment: @MrGumble You're right. You need to create an intermediate table for that. See updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You say very good, that it should have been a setting for the whole database, not to take care for every column to specify to be case insensitive.
Because there is one situation when you can go wrong. That is when you concatenate columns for comparision. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE col1||col2 NOT IN (SELECT col3||col4 FROM table2 t2)
```

Even if you set "collate nocase" on all fields, you have to set collation specifically here. So , in order for the comparision to be case insensitive, it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE col1||col2 NOT IN (SELECT col3||col4 FROM table2 t2) COLLATE NOCASE
```